# Filtering results of SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql

I want to retrieve all 20th century italian novelists' name.
I've written this:

`SELECT ?label
WHERE{
?novelist a yago:ItalianNovelists.
?novelist rdfs:label ?label.
FILTER (langMatches(lang(?label), "EN"))
}
ORDER BY ?label`

How can i filter the results?

Comment: What is it that would make them "20 century novelists"? If it is the year their notable works were published, you'll get only those for which there is such information. Maybe it would be safer to filter by when the novelist was born.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. Here I'd suggest two:

1. Use the pattern `?novelist dct:subject dbc:20th-century_novelists`, if you can rely on that classification.

```sql
SELECT ?label 
WHERE{
?novelist a yago:ItalianNovelists;
          rdfs:label ?label;
          dct:subject dbc:20th-century_novelists. 
FILTER (langMatches(lang(?label), "EN"))
}   
ORDER BY ?label
```

2. Define birth range or a life-span range. Example birth range:

```sql
SELECT ?label 
WHERE{
?novelist a yago:ItalianNovelists;
          rdfs:label ?label;
          dbo:birthDate ?date.     
BIND (YEAR(?date) AS ?year) 
FILTER (langMatches(lang(?label), "EN"))
FILTER (?year > 1882 && ?year < 1972)
}
ORDER BY ?label
```

With option 2 you will get more results but depending on the range, they might include novelists who haven't published anything in 20th century.

A third option would be the filter by the year of publishing. However, I wouldn't recommend it. First, it will give only results for those for whom such information is currently available in DBpedia, and that subset would most likely be smaller than the one from the first option. Second, depending on how you would define a 20 century novelist, the query results will omit those who wrote a novel in 20 century, which was published in 21.

Answer (score -2):

The language tag is in lowercase, so just replace `"EN:` with `"en"`.  Also, I find the following to be just as effective as using `langMatches`

```
 FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
```

Comment: langMatches does some fairly  sophisticated matching.  For instance, langMatches("en-us","EN") is true.  Direct equality matching wouldn't catch that.